# is it possible to use ubuntu 14(trusty ) as a live usb?

Tags: 14.04, live-usb

I have ubuntu 14 iso and also have successfully installed it alongside win8(uefi, and it was fairly difficult). now I am able to boot into both as needed.

But i want a os that i can carry around in an usb, along with user files. how can I install this ditro as live? is it even possible?

I am a total newbie to linux and having linux in my hdd is not motivating me to make the most out of it. if it was portable i would be a lot more interested.

thank you.

Comment: Of course. http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: all available answers seem to have a problem with "persistence" in 14.04

Comment: VM are also portable

Comment: Have you tried the built-in Startup Disk Creator application? Startup Disk Creator supports allocating reserved extra space on the USB drive for persistent file storage. All you need is a 2GB USB flash drive.

Comment: and do i run this startup disk creator from live environment or a previous complete install of linux in my hdd?

Comment: Startup Disk Creator is a built-in application in Ubuntu that can be run from any Ubuntu installation: hard drive, live environment or guest OS running in a virtual machine. I have used Startup Disk Creator to make an Ubuntu 14.04 live USB flash drive with persistent file storage.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the instruction on [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

note that you should check in the third figure "stored in reserved extra space" if you want to make it persistent and save all your customization and work inside the ubuntu environment. this will create a casper partition to store the data and it requires some space of your USB drive.

Comment: u mean to say 1. boot into linux i have in my hdd 2. follow the steps shown in the link?